# Setting RGB programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uicolor

How can we set the color of a label text programmatically, my color is R 77 G 104 B 159 
I have tried the below code but no use.

```
Label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:77.0 green:104.0 blue:159.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: UIColor's RGB components are scaled between 0 and 1, not up to 255.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Please try the code

```
Label.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:77.0/255.0f green:104.0/255.0f blue:159.0/255.0f alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: @FabioPoloni Actually, UIColor constructor takes CGFloat values, so a cast to CGFloat would be better. If you're targeting 64 bit exclusively, then those are `double` values and the `f` is a precision mistake.

Answer (score 5):

```
Label.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:77/255.f green:104/255.f blue:159/255.f alpha:1];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Label.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:77.0/255.0 green:104.0/255.0 blue:159.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: why deciding with 255.0 in it

Comment: colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha , each parameter specified as a value from 0.0(MIN) to 1.0 (MAX)

Comment: Because colors are 8bit values hence range lies b/w 0 to 255 hence divide by 255